# MySQL SELECT where there are two clauses and the second can be three values

Tags: mysql, count

I want to count rows in a table where there is correspondence with username and status. The status can be 1,2 or 3.

```
   | ID | username | status |
   --------------------------
   | 1  | john     |   1    |
   | 2  | john     |   2    |
   | 3  | john     |   3    |
   | 4  | john     |   4    |
   | 5  | jenna    |   2    |
   --------------------------
```

There are 4 entries for user John, but the last has status 4 so I don't need to count it.

So I made this query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE username = 'john' AND status = 1 OR 2 OR 3
```

but this counts every row even if there are records with a username and status not in the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM orders WHERE username = 'john' AND status IN ( 1,2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the field to each comparison and also make sure the conditions are grouped correctly:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM orders 
WHERE username = 'john' 
  AND (status = 1 OR status = 2 OR status = 3)
```

Shorter syntax:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM orders 
WHERE username = 'john' 
  AND status in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write something like "1 OR 2 OR 3", mysql treats that as an expression - "1 OR 2 OR 3" just evaluates to TRUE.

You can either expand it - `status = 1 OR status = 2 OR status = 3`
Or you can use the `IN` operator: `status IN (1, 2, 3)`